# How to get ThemeProvider in Pigment CSS working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, base-ui, pigment-css

I was trying to create a themed app with Pigment CSS using `ThemeProvider` and `createTheme` as described in the docs. But in my app the theme is not used.

I am using  @mui/base 5.0.0-beta.8 together with @mui/system 5.14.1 and @emotion/react 11.11.1

App.tsx:

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/system";
import {myTheme} from "./themes/mytheme.tsx";

export default function RdApp(): ReactElement {
    return <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
        <div>Hello world</div>
    </ThemeProvider>
}
```

thems/mytheme.ts:

```
import {createTheme} from "@mui/system";

export const myTheme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: "Arial"
    },
});
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dry-dew-z593g5

Answer (score 0):

The ThemeProvider doesn't affect HTML tags (`div` in your case) but only components that are aware of it.
Base UI components do not know how to read ThemeProvider values, as the library isn't tied to MUI System, Emotion, or any styling solution.